# How to sync SQLite database across platforms -- using Dropbox? Maybe Sky Drive?

Tags: c++, objective-c, sqlite, dropbox, onedrive

I really like SQLite that I use for both Windows WinAPI/C++, and iOS and OS X Cocoa/Objective-C development. I was thinking that if I had my app developed for iOS, OS X and Windows desktop, it would be really nice to be able to sync its SQLite database across those platforms. I know that Dropbox supports [Datastore APIs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore) that supposedly supports Data Sync APIs but there's no mentioning of SQLite...

Has anyone experimented if it's possible to sync SQLite database using any available cloud services?

- On Windows side -- using C, C++
- On iOS side -- using Objective-C

Comment: You don't ask a question as to what you have not implemented yet at stackoverflow.

Comment: @ElTomato: Well, I did implement SQLite for my Windows app, as well as the iOS app. I thought I mentioned it in my question.